# Drawings not visible after removeLayer method : leaflet

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, dc.leaflet.js

**Introduction**

As i am working on application which uses leaflet api. [Live Here](http://smartminds.cloudapp.net/betaSecurity/)
Where first user enter '1' as input to load the image on map.

Then user can draw different shapes(fences) using bottom-left buttons.
The 'eraser' button is suppose to remove all layers from map regarding CurrentFeatureGroup.

**Problem**

When we click on 'eraser' button, all shapes will be removed from map having currentfeaturegroup.
But after removing when we draw some other shapes, these shapes are invisible, although i have checked the function working properly.
I don't have idea how these shapes are now invisible.

**Script(which responsible to remove layers)**

```
L.easyButton('<img src="/delete.png">', function () {
                    map.removeLayer(currentFeatureGroup);
                    $('.leaflet-container').css('cursor', '');
                }).addTo(map);
```

> Please consider removeLayer, not clearLayer.If someone have any idea
>   about this problem please do help.Any kind of help or reference will
>   be appreciated, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you completely remove the featurelayer from the map by using `map.removeLayer(currentFeatureLayer)` where do you expect that any new features you draw after that will be added to? If you want to remove all current features from the featurelayer you really should be using `currentFeatureLayer.clearLayers()` which will keep the featurelayer so that you can continue to add features afterwards.